Unique extension of probability measure
I am stuck at this problem and would appreciate some insight.
Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and let $(\Omega',\mathcal{F}')$ be a measurable space with $\Omega \subseteq \Omega'$ and $\mathcal{F}=\{A' \in \mathcal{F}' : A' \subseteq \Omega \}$. Prove there exists a unique probability measure $\mathbb{P}'$ on $(\Omega',\mathcal{F}')$ that extends $\mathbb{P}$, i.e. $\mathbb{P}' \vert_\mathcal{F} = \mathbb{P}$. Give an explicit form of $\mathbb{P}'$.
If one can explicitly construct an extension of the prob. measure, then we have the existence. But what is the construction?
And furthermore, how can we prove the uniqueness?
EDIT: my thoughts on the problem.
Assume we have an extension $\mathbb{P}'$ as described above. Since $\mathbb{P}$ and $\mathbb{P}'$ are probability measures, we have $\mathbb{P}(\Omega)=1$ but also $\mathbb{P'}(\Omega')=1$. Now, consider $\mathbb{P}'(\Omega') = \mathbb{P'}(\Omega) + \mathbb{P}'(\Omega' \backslash \Omega) = \mathbb{P}(\Omega) + \mathbb{P}'(\Omega' \backslash \Omega) = 1 + \mathbb{P}'(\Omega' \backslash \Omega)$. Thus $\mathbb{P}'(\Omega' \backslash \Omega) = 0$ and also $\mathbb{P}'(A') = 0$ for all $A' \in \mathcal{F}', A' \subseteq \Omega' \backslash \Omega$.
I think we can write $\mathbb{P}'$ as follows:
Let $F \in \mathcal{F}'$, then by construction of $\mathcal{F}$ we know $F \cap \Omega \in \mathcal{F}$. So we define $\mathbb{P}'(F) = \mathbb{P}(F \cap \Omega)$ since the other contribution always vanishes.
As the extension $\mathbb{P}'$ is determined by $\mathbb{P}$ on $\mathcal{F}$ and vanishes on the remaining sets of $\mathcal{F}'$, the extension is also unique.

Hi Tom, this reads a bit like a textbook exercise, which makes people reluctant to respond unless you elaborate at bit on what you have tried.

Your thoughts are already a complete proof of the statement. Not sure what is the question here.
